# Spherical Travelling Salesman: Java library

Tags: open-source, library, java, optimization, geography

I have a list of 1000 cities around the globe, and want to find a short route that covers them all.

Is there an implementation of this in Java?

Requirements:

- Open source
- Easy to use: just call a method with as a parameter the list of cities. (Internally the library can use fancy things like AI or generic algorithms but it must be hidden)
- Works on a **sphere**. Most Travelling Salesman algorithms are [designed for flat worlds](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/45533/travelling-salesman-java-library) (small areas where Earth curvature is negligible).

Apparently Mathematica embeds a non-open-source [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132903/travelling-salesman-problem-on-the-unit-sphere) for this, but I need open source.

[image]