# Travelling Salesman: Java library

Tags: open-source, library, java, optimization, geography

I have a list of 1000 buildings of a city, and want to find a short route that covers them all.

Is there an implementation of this in Java?

Requirements:

- Open source
- Easy to use: just call a method with as a parameter the list of cities. (Internally the library can use fancy things like AI or generic algorithms but it must be hidden)
- Works in a flat world. The area is small, so Earth curvature is negligible.

[image]